# Behavior of SO_REUSEADDR when in TIME_WAIT state

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

Suppose the server has gone into the TIME_WAIT state, now the server again binds to the same port & is successful since the option REUSEADDR is set. Will it be able to accept new connection(s) followed by exchange of messages with the client(s) while still in the TIME_WAIT state.

This is specific to the usage of TCP in Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can accept new connections.  The existing connections will continue through the TIME_WAIT state, but new connections will go through the normal lifecycle (e.g. become established and allow exchange of messages) and only enter TIME_WAIT after they've been closed.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose the server has gone into the TIME_WAIT state

It hasn't. Your question is somewhat confused. It is (some of) the old connections that are in TIME_WAIT state, not the entire server, or the listening socket, which is in LISTENING state, by definition.

> now the server again binds to the same port & is successful since the option REUSEADDR is set. Will it be able to accept new connection(s)?

There is nothing in the TIME_WAIT state on the old connections that will prevent the new listening socket from accepting new connections.